# What command should I run in terminal to build a chrome application with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I've tried to build this chrome extension found on github (https://github.com/ConanXie/new-tab) 
using 'npm install' and 'npm run build' but it doesn't create it correcly. What command should I run to compile/build it?

thank you !

Comment: What do the docs say? _Always read the docs_.

Comment: i can't find them. I've seen that use react from the tsconfig.json file

Comment: Please may you add more details? What does “doesn’t create it correctly” mean? Is there an error? May you post that too?

Comment: when I build it on terminal it's not giving me error, but it doesn't create any build folder and just modifies the extension folder adding some javascript files.
Then if I try to upload the extension folder as an unpacketized extension on chrome it's returning a blank page.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the extension's code so you should ask its authors.